# How to change Frame Label1.caption to Form1.button1.click

Tags: delphi

There is no error in the code, but it doesn't work. Does anyone know why?

Form1.button1.click code

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
CHS : Tframe1;
begin
CHS.label1.caption := 'ABC';

end;
```

Comment: The value of `CHS` is undefined (since it is a local variable of an unmanaged type -- it's basically a random address). This is very much an error: you can corrupt the memory of your process, or get an access violation error. `CHS` is a variable that can be made to point to *some* `Tframe1` object. You have to specify *which* such object you want it to point to, like `CHS := my frame; CHS.label1.Caption := 'ABC'`. Likely your frame is a control on the form named `Frame1`, and so `Frame1.Label1.Caption := 'ABC'` will do.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand 
CHS is defined as TFrame1.

CHS is not defined as Frame1.

Comment: `TFrame1` is a *class*, a *type*. You need `CHS` to point to a particular instance of this class. If you have dropped a `TMyFrame` on your form, it will be named `MyFrame1`. You can have five instances of your frame class.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand More correct to say that you can have *any number* of instances - whether that's one, five, zero, or any other number.

Comment: @J...: Really, I had no idea! :)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand For OP's benefit, of course - I didn't want them walking away thinking the IDE allowed them five instances of a class and that was it. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to insert your `frame1` into your `form1` in the IDE's designer. For this purpose go to the designer for the `form1` and click into the palette in the section `Standard` the tree list item `Frames`. Now you should see your `frame1` in the list. Otherwise, your unit is not properly integrated into the project. Select the `frame1` and place it on the form.
2. As a result, you will see the automatically inserted line
   `frame1: TFrame1` in the class declaration of the `TForm1`.
3. You can access the `label1` on your frame within the button click event method as follow:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  frame1.label1.caption := 'ABC';
end;
```

Comment: ` unit FA; 
 type 
  TFrame1 = class(TFrame) `
--------------------------------
 `form1 
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
 uses FA; `

Isn't it like this?

Comment: This is the unit with your Tframe1. Now you need to add this frame1 to your form. For this purpose go to the designer for form1 and click within `Standard` the tree list item `Frames`.  Now you should see your frame1 in the list. Select this frame1 and place it on the form. See additional steps in point 1.

Comment: Isn't this exactly what @AndreasRejbrand said in his original comment?

Comment: I didn't understand the IDE.

Because I've used Frame for the first time...